# Cubic Ubuntu virtual environment not working

Tags: pi-4, linux, ubuntu

When I try using Cubic Ubuntu to make a custom image of Ubuntu, I put in the ISO file, rename some things here and there, and click next. After it copies some stuff and does its thing, it tries to enter the 'Cubic virtual environment' and keeps failing and retrying with the same error: "execv(/bin/bash, /bin/sh) failed: Exec format error". You can also see this error in better detail in the included image. Do I need to run it a certain way? Do I need to do something differently?

Comment: maybe the problem is with `rename some things here and there`

Comment: Welcome to [raspberrypi.se] - where's the included image?